# How to rename dictionary keys to follow sequential order?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value, sequential

My code processes dictionaries, and most dictionaries come in the following format:

```
#Default
d = {0:'a', 1: 'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4: 'e', 5:'f', 6:'g', 7:'h', 8:'i', 9:'j', 10:'k'}
```

In some cases however, dictionaries miss key-value pairs and come in a following format:

```
d1 = {0:'a', 1: 'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4: 'e', 6:'g', 7:'h', 8:'i', 9:'j', 10:'k'}
d2 = {1: 'b', 2:'c', 4: 'e', 6:'g', 7:'h', 8:'i', 9:'j'}
```

How would I rearrange the keys in these dictionaries to follow sequential format as seen in the expected output below?

```
expected1 = {0:'a', 1: 'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', 4: 'e', 5:'g', 6:'h', 7:'i', 8:'j', 9:'k'}
expected2 = {0: 'b', 1:'c', 2: 'e', 3:'g', 4:'h', 5:'i', 6:'j'}
```

Comment: a dictionary like the one you describe is basically a `list` with the keys being the index positions.

Comment: What is the goal of what are you trying to do? When you create a dictionary the key has a semantic, it is not recommended to change it, as stated by @Ma0 list is more adequate

Comment: The goal is that instances, object classes and other metrics are paired as values of the keys as output. Once it is detected that a object class is not desired, the key-value is discarded from the dictionary. Later on during processing other some elements are used from the other elements in the values and it is important these keep in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple dictionary comprehension:

```
d2 = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(d2.values())}
```

As said by Ma0 in comments, a list would be more adequate. You can retrieve the list as `d1.values()`.

Comment: or `d2 = {i: v for i, v in enumerate(d2.values())}` assuming python 3.6+

Comment: @Ma0 Yes, better.

Comment: {k: d[k] for k in range(len(d.keys))} results in TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()

Comment: {i: v for i, v in enumerate(d2.values())} gives the expected output, thanks !

Comment: My bad, missed the ().

Comment: {k: d1[k] for k in range(len(d1.keys()))}
KeyError: 5

Comment: @Rivered Yes.. I typed that definitely too fast thinking about the enumerate suggested after by Ma0..